# Works fine in Firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery, mozilla

Here is my code ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

   <form id="foo">
    <label for="bar">A bar</label>
    <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
   </form>

   <div id ="onsuccess"></div>
 </body>

</html>
Javsacript:

<script>
// variable to hold request
var request;
// bind to the submit event of our form
$("#foo").submit(function(event){

  $("#onsuccess").html('<img src="a.gif"/>');
    var $form = $(this);

    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "a.txt",
        type: "post",
        timeout:30000,  
        dataType: "text", 
        data: serializedData,

    });

    // callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        $("#onsuccess").html(response);

    });

    // callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occured: " +
            textStatus, errorThrown         
        );
    });

    // callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // reenable the inputs
       // $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    // prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();


});
/*
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show();
 }).ajaxStop(function(){
    $(this).hide();
 });
*/

$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(){

/*console.log("you are scrolling the page");
console.log("window scroll top ="+ $(window).scrollTop() );
console.log ("window height =" + $(window).height());
console.log("document height =" + $(document).height());
*/

if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()-$(window).height())
        {
$("#onsuccess").append("<p>i was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page end i was called because you are about to reach the page end</p>");
    }

});    
});
</script>
```

Here i am trying to dynamically append the page through a random text....just studying the functionality of Ajax..i checked on mozilla and it worked...but not on chrome. any ideas..thanks

in chrome, i can see the spinner, the content of txt file doesn't load up...while in firefox..the content of txt file loads up and scroll function also works...((there is no question of scrolling thing in chrome since the document is empty and i can't scroll it down)) please tell me what more inputs should i give you..no error in firebug –

Comment: I guessing in chrome the console logs aren't firing... What happens if you change it a input button type instead of submit so the event.prevent default diet fire. Curious if the preent default stops the promised event from firing. Also, in debug can you see if the Ajax call is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your submit handler `$("#foo").submit(function(event){...});` inside you `document.ready()` handler.

Like so

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#foo").submit(function (event) {

        $("#onsuccess").html('<img src="a.gif"/>');
        var $form = $(this);

        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "a.txt",
            type: "post",
            timeout: 30000,
            dataType: "text",
            data: serializedData,

        });

        // callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // log a message to the console
            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
            $("#onsuccess").html(response);

        });

        // callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // log the error to the console
            console.error(
                "The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
        });

        // callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {
            // reenable the inputs
            // $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });

        // prevent default posting of form
        event.preventDefault();


    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        /*console.log("you are scrolling the page");
console.log("window scroll top ="+ $(window).scrollTop() );
console.log ("window height =" + $(window).height());
console.log("document height =" + $(document).height());
*/
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            $("#onsuccess").append("<p>i was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page endi was called because you are about to reach the page end i was called because you are about to reach the page end</p>");
        }

    });
});
```